# How to update my code from Terminal for Github

Tags: c++, github

Alright, so I have started using Github to easily share my code, and to keep track of updates. My main problem is that I have put my code in my repo, but I am not sure how to update it without saving the updates as a different file, and then pushing that to my repo.

Short version: Is there a way to update my code without pushing a whole new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but if I'm understanding you correctly, you can do the following:

- Edit the files you need to change
- Do git add for each file to make git track the changes i.e. add the files to the staging area.
- When you're ready to commit, do git commit to commit the changes. This will commit locally.
- When you are ready to push up to github, do a git push. Git is smart about sending up the changes, not whole files.

Git takes a while to understand and it sounds like you're not there yet. I would spend some time going through at least the first few chapters of the Pro Git book, which is available free online at http://progit.org/book/.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can do all the things stated in the bullet points. I have saved one of my code sources, which were already uploaded to Github, and I checked the site after making the changes to the source, and it had not updated itself. So how do I update sources that were already added to Github. I will be using Terminal.

Comment: So you're saying you edited the file, did git add, git commit, and then git push? If so, did the push succeed? What output did you see? Can you paste the exact commands you entered here?

Comment: This is what happened when I do, git commit, since I was unsure if I should do, git commit gameoflife.cpp


# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
# modified:   gameoflife2.cpp
# modified:   gameoflife3.cpp
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# gameoflife2.cpp.bak
# gameoflife3
# gameoflife3.cpp.bak
# gameoflife3.o
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: And when I do git push, it says Everything up to date. I go to my repository, and the file was not updated.

Comment: The answer to your question is in that output from git commit: you need to do git add to tell git to track the changes in your file. As I said before, git is different from other source code control systems you may have used, so this may be surprising. Unless you do git add, git will not track your change, even if you've previously added that file in a previous commit. I strongly suggest you follow my earlier advice and read up the first few chapters in the free Pro Git book I linked to above.